# Infinite expression encountered in NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration

Trying to solve the following ODE:

```
solw = NDSolve[{0.75 (w[t] w''[t] - w'[t]^2) + w[t]^3 == 1/2 (1 + Tanh[100 t]), 
    w[0] == 0, w'[0] == 0}, w, {t, 0, 2}, Method -> "MethodOfLines"];
wsol[t_] := Evaluate[w[t] /. solw]
```

However, `NDSolve` gives an error:

> Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/0. encountered.

I can't figure out why this happens and how to overcome this. Any idea will be appreciated.

Reviewed some related questions like [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/84018/powerinfy-infinite-expression-1-0-encountered-ode-solution-using-ndsolve) or [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/87395/infinite-expression-error-ndsolve), but this does not help.

Comment: It's due to your initial conditions. Can you start at a different point?

Comment: I start from `t=0.0001`, it gies the same error. I also try to alter `w[0]` and try with `w[0]=0.0001`, but the solution is highly oscillating. This should not be the case.

Comment: You need to change the left endpoint in `{t, 0, 2}` as well if you're doing the perturbation. This is a known limitation of `NDSolve[]`. May I suggest using `$MachineEpsilon` instead of `0`?

Comment: Tried with `$MachineEpsilon`, but the solution amplitude becomes 10^106.

Comment: Speaking of... your code did not provide the definition for `f[t]`; please edit your question to include it.

Comment: Thanks! Done. I suspect that there is no any singularity. Mathematica just devides both sides to `w[t]` to get a Rayleigh equation. Not sure.

Comment: "I suspect that there is no any singularity." - it's certainly possible, it's just that `NDSolve[]` on its own can't cope, as I said earlier. It has similar trouble with e.g. the Bessel equation.

Comment: Look at your ode at `t = 0`.  With your ic's you get `0 == 2/3`.  Even with a small initial `t > 0`, w''[t] will have to be huge to match the ode initially, which probably is the cause of high oscillatory behavior.  For this equation, NDSolve does ok with less extreme ic's.

Comment: @BillWatts well noted. However, when I impose `w[0]=0` and `w'[0]>0`, I will get the same error. Anyway, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your initial conditions do not satisfy the ODE:

```
eqn = 0.75 (w[t] w''[t]-w'[t]^2)+w[t]^3==1/2 (1+Tanh[100 t]);
eqn /. t->0 /. {w[0]->0, w'[0]->0}
```

> False

The only way your initial conditions can satisfy the ODE is if $$\lim_{t\to 0} w(t) w''(t) = \frac{2}{3}$$ which means that $$\lim_{t\to 0} w''(t) \to \infty$$

This is why [`NDSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolve) is unable to compute a solution, and why you get `Power::infy` messages. If you choose initial conditions that can satisfy the ODE, then [`NDSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolve) has no problems:

```
solw = NDSolveValue[{eqn, w[0] == (1/2)^(1/3), w'[0] == 0}, w, {t, 0, 2}];

Plot[solw[t], {t, 0, 2}]
```

[image: plot]